# Extract a substring if it has an exact match in another vector

Tags: regex, r

***Update***: the first version of this question was implicitly asking how to extract a substring if it has **ANY** match in another vector, for which @Colonel Beauvel provided an elegant response:

> This does the trick, base `R`:
>
> ```
> newname = sapply(nametitle, function(u){
>     bool = sapply(name, function(x) grepl(x, u))
>     if(any(bool)) name[bool][1] else NA })
>
> newname 
> John Smith, MD PhD       Jane Doe, JD 
>             "John"             "Jane"
> ```

*However, I did not realize that I was actually asking for a way to find **exact** matches until the function kindly contributed did not work for all elements in my vector. Therefore, the following is my revised question.*

---

Say I have the following character vector of generic names and their academic degrees:

```
nametitle <- c("John Smith, MD PhD", "Jane Doe, JD", "John-Paul Jones, MS")
```

And I have a "look-up" vector of first names:

```
name <- c("John", "Jane", "Mark", "Steve")
```

What I want to do is search each element of `nametitle`, and if part of the element (i.e., a substring of each string) is an exact match of an element from `name`, then in a new vector `newname`, write that element of `nametitle` with the corresponding element of `name`, or if there is no exact match, write the original value from `nametitle`.

Therefore, what I'd expect the proper function to do is return `newname` with the three elements below:

`[1] "John"  [2] "Jane"  [3]  "John-Paul Jones, MS"`

I've attempted the following using the function contributed above:

```
newname = sapply(nametitle, function(u){
  bool = sapply(name, function(x) grepl(x, u))
  if(any(bool)) name[bool][1] else NA })
```

Which performs just fine for elements `"John Smith, MD Phd"` and `"Jane Doe, JD"`, but not for `"John-Paul Jones, MS"` -- this element is replaced with `"John"` in the new vector `newname`.

There may be a simple change that can be made to the original function contributed by @Colonel Beauvel to resolve this issue, but using nested `sapply` functions is throwing me through a loop (pun intended?). Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a subset of your real data that raises the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick, base `R`:

```
newname = sapply(nametitle, function(u){
    bool = sapply(name, function(x) grepl(x, u))
    if(any(bool)) name[bool][1] else NA
})

#>newname
#John Smith, MD PhD       Jane Doe, JD 
#            "John"             "Jane"
```

Comment: Holy cow. How has this very helpful function not already been incorporated into a package? Thanks again @Colonel Beauvel.

Comment: Hi @Colonel Beauvel. Please see my revised question, and thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way. First, create a regex pattern based on your `name` vector:

```
pattern <- paste0(".*(?<=\\s|^)(", paste(name, collapse = "|"), ")(?=\\s|$).*")
# [1] ".*(?<=\\s|^)(John|Jane|Mark|Steve)(?=\\s|$).*"
```

If you use this pattern, a single `sub` command will do the trick:

```
sub(pattern, "\\1", nametitle, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "John"                "Jane"                "John-Paul Jones, MS"
```